# How to convert imagesource to byte[] or stream in uwp?

Tags: uwp

I have a ImageSource imageSource, and want to convert to byte array or stream, how?I tried

```
WriteableBitmap bitmap = imageSource as WriteableBitmap;
var stream = bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
```

But bitmap is null...

Comment: Sure you want to get the raw pixel buffer, or perhaps get an encoded frame, e.g. a PNG?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814426/how-to-convert-imagesource-to-byte-array/47192922#47192922

Comment: I' m afraid this does not work in uwp.

Answer (score 0):

You should sure the imageSource is WriteableBitmap for it can be BitmapImage or WriteableBitmap ……

If the imageSource is WriteableBitmap that you can write your code.

But if the  imageSource is BitmapImage that you should use `WriteableBitmapEx`

The first is use nuget to download WriteableBitmapEx.

And then you can change it to WriteableBitmap.

```
 WriteableBitmap image = await BitmapFactory.New(1, 1).FromContent((BitmapImage).UriSource);
```

And then you can convert WriteableBitmap to stream.

If your imageSource is RenderTargetBitmap that you can use this code.

```
private async Task<string> ToBase64(RenderTargetBitmap bitmap)
{
    var bytes = (await bitmap.GetPixelsAsync()).ToArray();
    return await ToBase64(bytes, (uint)bitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)bitmap.PixelHeight);
}
```

See(Chinese language):https://lindexi.gitee.io/post/win10-uwp-%E8%AF%BB%E5%8F%96%E4%BF%9D%E5%AD%98WriteableBitmap-BitmapImage.html

Comment: for WriteableBitmap, you can download/install from here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WriteableBitmapEx/

Comment: Anyway, the link is broken and your code isn't clear enough. For example, `.UriSource` is invoked on which object?

Comment: @YoavFeuerstein Thx and I fix it.